# What statistics can be used to describe the volatility of a time series?

Tags: statistics, time-series, discrete-mathematics, describe

Below is an image of four time series in the link above; each series has only three discrete values (1, 2, 3) marked with different colors (blue, yellow, red). Apparently, the second one shows the strongest volatility while the fourth one shows the least volatility. But how can I use a statistic to describe such volatility specifically?

[image: Image of Four time series]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that x_0 is your starting point, and the graphs are measured in a common unit of time t, then by comparison, sum(abs(x_[n-1] - x_[n])) from x = 1 to x = n divided by t will provide a scalar that will compare the relative volatility of the time series. This is not statistics (well, not complicated statistics, it is an average), but essentially the absolute value of the summations of the variations of the systems divided by the time in which the changes took place. The greatest value will be the most variant of the series.

Comment: Thank you very much.That helps a lot. Is there any details about this method?It would be great if you give me some references about it.

Comment: Considered a statistical measure, it is the most basic of all statistics, an average. It is the summated change in values divided by the time the change took place, providing the average change over time. There is no formal theory for the calculation I gave you, it is just a simple average. The unusual part is the measurement of the variation, the ABS of the change. Now, if you consider the values not as ordinal values, but as a state classification, and not a number, then you should convert the transitions to unit counts, and in the same spirit, you can calculate the transition volatility.